# What is the best time and space complexity achievable with finding a number in various number ranges?

Tags: algorithm, information-retrieval

I want to ask a user a 2 number range to generate a third one. *(This is done to set a custom selling price following a market trend.)*

For example, between 1 and 2, generated number is 3. Between 2 and 3, it will be 4.5 *(this number is fixed by the user and we must store it)*.

Then, when I will be processing some data and will just have the market price number, I will have to know in which number range it is "located" and find the according generated number.

I thought about storing 3 datas : startingValue, endingValue and userValue. But this means that I have to retrieve all data and browse each number ranger each time, which leads to N in space and time complexity.

I somehow feel this could be done in constant time.

Would you have any idea ? Or am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: Do you have a guarantee that (i) all input values (intervals) possess an output value (generated number) and that (ii) there is no ambiguity (that for instance there is no between 1 and 3 value is 3 and between 2 and 4 value is 4) ? If so the answer is very simple

Comment: Yes, for both of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you can get your answer in constant time (I think it's not too hard to prove that it is not feasible in constant time under classic complexity assumptions).
Nevertheless, you can find your answer in `O(log n)` where `n` is the number of ranges you have to store.

All you need to do is to store your ranges in a sorted array as follows:
imagine you have two ranges `(a, b) -> v1` and `(b ,c) -> v2` (your answer to the comment implies that the ranges are adjacent).
Then you can use an array of tuples `[(a, v1), (b, v2)]` and use a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to find the corresponding value.

Comment: I could do it in log(n) complexity thanks to your advice. Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

I could do it in **log(n)** space/time complexity thanks to m.raynal answer. The fact that the range were adjacent makes it possible.

It uses recursion.

```
function findTheRightPriceRange(arrayOfPriceRanges, priceInput, counter = 0) {
  if (
    !Array.isArray(arrayOfPriceRanges) ||
    (Array.isArray(arrayOfPriceRanges) && arrayOfPriceRanges).length === 0
  ) {
    return -2;
  }
  counter++;
  let middleArrayIndex = Math.floor(arrayOfPriceRanges.length / 2);
  let currentPointer = arrayOfPriceRanges[middleArrayIndex];

  if (priceInput >= currentPointer[0] && priceInput <= currentPointer[1]) {
    return currentPointer[2];
  }

  if (priceInput <= currentPointer[0]) {
    return findTheRightPriceRange(
      arrayOfPriceRanges.splice(0, middleArrayIndex),
      priceInput,
      counter
    );
  }
  if (priceInput >= currentPointer[0]) {
    return findTheRightPriceRange(
      arrayOfPriceRanges.splice(
        middleArrayIndex,
        arrayOfPriceRanges.length - 1
      ),
      priceInput,
      counter
    );
  }

  return -1;
}
```